Replicate Chat GPT typing animation in React for lists
I got here a very tricky problem here, and i don't see any solutions for it.
So, the problem is next:
I have a web socket subscription where on each message i do get small chunks of json.
For example when message 1 i get this object:
{
 ObjectKeyHere: ['string 1', 'string 2']
}

in message 2 i get i could get this object:
{
 ObjectKeyHere: ['string 1', 'string 2'],
 AnotherObjectKeyHere: ['string 3', 'string 4']
}

While i am getting these chunks, i need to render and apply typing animation like Chat GPT does, just on specific new set of data that just came in the last chunk.
This is something approximative i am trying to render:

I tried multiple solutions and ideas, but nothing works properly. The idea is that I am trying to apply that typing animation not on simple texts, but for a whole list. Here bellow is my component:
const TypingList = ({ data, speed = 50 }) => {
  const [currentChar, setCurrentChar] = useState({
    value: '',
    index: 0,
  });
  const [displayedData, setDisplayedData] = useState([]);

  let timeoutId = null;

  const typeNextCharacter = () => {
    if (currentChar.index >= data.length) return;

    const nextChar = data[currentChar.index];

    setCurrentChar((prev) => ({ ...prev, value: prev.value + nextChar, index: prev.index + 1 }));
    setDisplayedData((prev) => [...prev, nextChar]);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(typeNextCharacter, speed);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    typeNextCharacter();
    return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  }, [data]);

  const renderListItem = (item, displayed) => (
    <li key={item} className={displayed ? '' : 'hidden'}>{item}</li>
  );

  return (
    <div className={styles.typingText}>
      <ul>
        {displayedData.map((item, i) => renderListItem(item, i <= currentChar.index))}
        {renderCursor()}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TypingList;

Not sure if the problem that i described is clear...?
If maybe anyone did something like that, would be great to see what's the best approach and solution for that?
This is the example on playcode what i am trying to do guys:
https://playcode.io/1927229

Is there a reason you would like to do this with React rather than with CSS? You can achieve this with pure CSS and a lot less code.

second Marcs comment. thats a lot of code, you can do this with keyframes in css. bonus tip if you ask chatGPT how its done it will tell you

Can we assume that the next object must contain the previous object definitely? I see your second object is containing the first object from your sample data.

@NIKE yes, next chunk objects will always get all the data inside ( previous data + new data )

@MarcInglis hmm, but i am wondering how would that work just with pure css? Because every time i get a new chunk of data, it will be a new render, and it will apply the same animation again and again for the data from first chunks. Do you see my point of view?

these chunks of data that i get are some sort of streaming data...

Here is the playcode with what i am trying to do guys: https://playcode.io/1927229
